# Как правильно написать?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать: "Ходатайствовать о назначении на должность военрука Петрова Ильи"? Или "Петрова Илью"?

Answer (score 1):

Ходатайствовать о назначении Петрова Ильи на должность военрука.

Answer (score -1):

Ходатайствовать о назначении на должность военрука Петрова Ильи, если это была должность сейчас Петрова Ильи, и на неё кого-то назначают. Но так не говорят. Грамматически верно: "Ходатайствовать о назначении на должность военрука Петрова Илью". Понятно, кого на какую должность хотят назначить.

Comment: Всё-таки с существительным "назначение" нужно ставить зависимое слово в родительный падеж. Был бы глагол, "назначить", ставили бы в винительный -- Петрова Илью.